# how to setup token for the first time login with axios?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework, axios, token

In my React app I have

```
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Token ${localStorage.getItem("token")}\`;
```

to send token with each request.

Now, I am trying to login for the first time to Django rest server, using djoser package, but I get this 401 response: `{"detail":"Invalid token."}`

I guess because there's no token yet.

settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 1000,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

Should I do something on the frontend or backend, and what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation points out to login you should reach the endpoint `/auth/token/login/` and provide `username` & `password` to retrieve a new the token.

regarding the `Authorization` you could do as:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token ? `Token ${token}` : null
```

or using iterceptors:

```
  axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    config.headers.Authorization =  token ? `Token ${token}` : null
    return config;
  });
```

Comment: the problem was that my code was sending '`Authorization: Token null`' instead of '`Authorization: null`'. The interceptor works better than default, because it sends token immediatelly for automatic request after login